# Uncommon 4 pin DC 19V power socket - what type of connection is this [picture]?

Tags: power-supply

A friend of mine picked up a [Pioneer "Dream PC"](http://www.pcauthority.com.au/Review/17447,pioneer-dream-pc-p2400,specs.aspx) for real cheap at a charity sale, just because it looked strange. But it did not come with a power cable.

Any idea what this type of connection this is? Or any other type of device that uses this type of connection, so we can try track down a cable for the machine...

[image: 4 pin power connection on DreamPC]

Comment: Update: there are no other information markings on the device to help determine it's power requirements.

Comment: Does the power supply not have the manufacturer & model number on it somewhere? That'd help greatly.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it may be a Kycon [KPPX-4P](http://www.mouser.com/Search/Refine.aspx?Keyword=806-KPPX-4P).

Comment: Good find. I pulled the specification and it appears to be keyed the same way as the image above as well.

Answer (score 4):

The socket shown in the photo is of a snap and lock DC power connector. (If by happy accident you should happen upon one, snap and lock power cables are identifiable by the presence of one or two wide arrows in the plastic covering molded over the plug ends.) Many manufacturers use -- or have used -- this type of connector -- Dell and Toshiba, just to name a couple of the largest.

Mind that this is *not* the same item as the superficially similar 4 pin mini-DIN connector used in low-power cables for audio, video or serial data. The pins on the snap and lock are thicker than those on the mini DIN, and are arranged in a more four-square, less trapezoidal layout. This is done to prevent introducing, say, 100 Watts to components designed to handle less than one Watt.

I mention the disparity because suppliers will incorrectly refer to the connectors as DIN or mini-DIN. Here's an example, in a [Third-party Gateway replacement](http://www.sunvalleytek.com/compatible-gateway-laptop-ac-adapter-19v-79a-4pin-din-p-873.html).

In any event, without a schematic or pin-out and power specifications from the manufacturer, ensuring the proper polarity and voltage across the connection is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a power connector like that, but it's on the back of my external HDD case (but not a 19V DC connector). Because the PC is set to take 19VDC, you can't just take out the connector and wire up a power cable. You'd have to find something that can output 19 volts at the appropriate wattage (any other stickers on the PC about that?)

My only suggestion for help would be to look to [Daniel Rutter](http://www.dansdata.com/) for some information. He lives in Australia and seems to be able to find information on the most random bits of hardware - and since this PC seems to be an Australia-only PC, he might be able to help. You can get a hold of him [by email](http://www.dansdata.com/contact.html), and you might even make an ["Ask Dan" column](http://www.dansdata.com/askdan00045.htm)!

Comment: Thanks for that, will contact Dan. To answer your question the device has no other markings on it for information.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty odd! No idea what it is, but if you got it at a charity sale, maybe you can get the cable somewhere like that too. In the US, Goodwill and Value Village often have a pretty large assortment of random cables. It'll take a lot of hunting...

Can you get in touch with the manufacturers?

Otherwise get out the soldering iron and make your own!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a milspec connector of some form. I've made more than my share of cables using similar connectors where I worked out of high school :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to get a DC power supply second hand that can output 19V and a few hundred watts, figure out which plug is power and which is ground, then power it up and hope it doesn't smoke.

[image]